# How to delete image from array if display="none" using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using **Vue.js** in my project.  I have a background of images which are animated, they are moving from up to down. Everything connected to the random image, position and etc is inside `created()`:

```
const vue = require("@/assets/images/vue.png");
const bootstrap = require("@/assets/images/bootstrap.png");
const bulma = require("@/assets/images/bulma.png");

export default {
  name: "randImg",
  data() {
    return {
      images: [
        vue,
        bootstrap,
        bulma
      ],
      addedImage: [],
      imgTop: -100,
      imgLeft: -100,
      imgHeight: 64,
      imgWidth: 64,
      changeInterval: 250
    }
  },
  created() {
    const randomImg = func => setInterval(func, this.changeInterval);
    randomImg(this.randomImage);
    randomImg(this.addImage);
    randomImg(this.randomPosition);
  },
  mounted: function () {
    if (this.addedImage[i] = {
      style: {display: `none`}
    }) {
      this.addedImage.remove(this.addedImage[i]);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    randomImage() {
      const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length);
      this.selectedImage = this.images[idx];
    },
    randomPosition() {
      const randomPos = twoSizes => Math.round(Math.random() * twoSizes);
      this.imgTop = randomPos(screen.height / 10 - this.imgHeight);
      this.imgLeft = randomPos(screen.width - this.imgWidth);
    },
    addImage() {
      if (this.addedImage.length > 500) {
        this.addedImage.splice(0, 300);
      } else {
        this.addedImage.push({
          style: {
            top: `${this.imgTop}px`,
            left: `${this.imgLeft}px`,
            height: `${this.imgHeight}px`,
            width: `${this.imgWidth}px`
          },
          src: this.selectedImage
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

css

```
.image {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: animationDrop;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  filter: blur(3px);
  will-change: transform;
}

@keyframes animationDrop {
  15% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }

  80% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }

  100% {
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and html

```
<div class="randImg">
    <img class="image" :style="image.style"
         :src="image.src"
         v-for="image in addedImage">
</div>
```

My site is lagging because images are adding to the DOM infinitely.  The idea of my animation is that when my image is on keyframe 100% it will have display none. So I decide to simply create an if statement inside `mounted()` but it doesn't work; I get the error message "ReferenceError: i is not defined".

How can I delete the images when their display become none?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are using jquery but if you are then you can use the [visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) by adding a class to images and remove those images which are not visible?

Comment: i am not using it...

Comment: I think you're on the right track with your `this.addedImage.splice(0, 300);` -- instead of continually adding to the array and trying to detect the display of individual images in the DOM to know when to remove them, limit your array to a reasonable length and just remove the oldest ones as you add new ones.  (Waiting until there are 500 of them and then chopping off 300 at once may simply be too many to handle.)

Comment: can you explain it a bit deeper? i am trying to understand but still not :)

Comment: Sure, see answer below.  (I still have a bad habit of trying to answer questions in comments....)

Answer (score 1):

You want each image to persist for five seconds (based on your animation-duration), and you're adding one image every 250ms (based on your changeInterval variable).  This means that your image array needs to contain a maximum of twenty images, rather than the 500 you're currently limiting it to.

You could control this by modifying your addImage function to drop the oldest image before adding the newest one.  (You're already doing this, except that you're waiting until five hundred of them have built up and then splicing off three hundred at once; better to do it one at a time:)

```
addImage() {
  if (this.addedImage.length > 20) {
    this.addedImage.shift() // remove oldest image (the first one in the array)
  }
  // add a new image to the end of the array:
  this.addedImage.push({
    style: {
      top: `${this.imgTop}px`,
      left: `${this.imgLeft}px`,
      height: `${this.imgHeight}px`,
      width: `${this.imgWidth}px`
    },
    src: this.selectedImage
  });
}
```

There's no need to read the display value from the DOM, you can just depend on the timing to ensure that the images aren't removed before they're supposed to; modifying the array is all that's necessary to remove the elements from the DOM.  (You could harmlessly leave a few extra in the array length, just in case, but there's no need to go all the way to 500.)   `mounted()` wouldn't be useful for this case because that function only runs once, when the component is first drawn onto the page, before there's anything in the addedImages array.

Comment: i have another problem now... could i send you this project?

Comment: If you have a different problem you should ask that as its own question; if it's related to the above can you please describe what the issue is, instead of just linking to your repo?

Comment: lets say, its connected :) now images are animating discontinuously!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: well, that is why i send repository... it's hard to explain :D

Answer (score 0):

Using v-if to remove images which style is `display: none`. And i think you can
 delete all code in `mounted()`.

```
<div class="randImg">
  <template v-for="image in addedImage">
    <img v-if="image.style.display !== 'none'" class="image" 
       :style="image.style" :src="image.src">
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to delete my image from array when display is none!

Comment: i want it because images are adding infinitely to the array