# how to stop function in 5 seconds? Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

this is my code

```
 setInterval(this.randomImage, 250);
 setInterval(this.randomPosition, 250);
 setInterval(this.addImage, 250);
```

i want to stop addImage function in 5 seconds because images are adding infinitely!

i tried to do it by this way

```
let timesRun = 0;
const intervalAddImage = setInterval(function () {
  timesRun += 1;
  if (timesRun === 60) {
    clearInterval(intervalAddImage)
  }
  this.addImage();

}, 250);

intervalAddImage();
```

but it doesn't work...

i am using Vue.js!

Comment: Did you check the console for any error message?

Comment: intervalAddImage is not a function

Comment: Can you show your whole code? where `this` came from, do you run this from object, or you use implicit global/window object?

Comment: @jcubic setTimeout(setInterval(this.addImage, 250), 5000); ?? in that case function will not stop

Comment: that deleted comment was mistake. Check my other comment.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) documentation? It states that intervals can be cleared using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

Comment: @jcubic i have whole code in my previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55496947/how-to-delete-image-from-array-if-display-none-using-vue-js/55498634?noredirect=1#comment97707441_55498634

Comment: then `this.timesRun` will be global variable on window not prop of your object. you need to use arrow function `setInterval(() => {}, x)` or use `function() {}.bind(this)` or set this to variable `var self = this` if this.timesRun suppose to be your const then you need to use let and don't use `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code runs a task every 250ms and stops after 5sec. I hope this will give you some inspiration.

```js
var intervalId = setInterval(() => console.log("running"), 250);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(intervalId), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake: do not use `this` without being careful: you should take time to understand [how `this` works in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

In your code, you increment `this.timesRun`, but you test on `timesRun` which is never incremented.

This sample will work as you expect:

```js
let timesRun = 0; 
//const addImage = this.addImage;
const intervalAddImage = setInterval(function () {
  timesRun += 1;
  if (timesRun === 60) {
    clearInterval(intervalAddImage);
  }
  //addImage();
  console.log("Hello", timesRun);
}, 250);
```

Comment: i need addImage

Comment: If you need to call `addImage`, i've updated the snippet. You'll find lines to uncomment to enable it. Another way would be to `bind` the function to the `this` value, so that `this` is what you want it to be inside the function.

Comment: But please, take time to read how `this` works in JavaScript, otherwise, you'll encounter a lot of problems. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

So it works)

```
let timesRun = 0; // just change to this
function addImage(timesRun) { console.log(timesRun)}
const intervalAddImage = setInterval(function () {
    timesRun += 1; // just change to this
    if (timesRun === 4) {
        clearInterval(intervalAddImage)
        return; // add this
    }
    addImage(timesRun);
}, 250);
```

Comment: "intervalAddImage is not a function"

Comment: @GermanVaranytsya just remove the call to `intervalAddImage();` because that's not the function but number.